# Usage of -d32 and -d64 while launching Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I read below excerpt from [JDK FAQ's](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_layering)

> How do I select between 32 and 64-bit operation? What's the default?
>   The options -d32 and -d64 have been added to the Java launcher to
>   specify whether the program is to be run in a 32 or 64-bit
>   environment. On Solaris these correspond to the ILP32 and LP64 data
>   models, respectively.  Since Solaris has both a 32 and 64-bit J2SE
>   implementation contained within the same installation of Java, you can
>   specify either version.  If neither -d32 nor -d64 is specified, the
>   default is to run in a 32-bit environment.

Now to test this, I logged in into my 64 bit Ubuntu guest OS and installed 64 bit JDK version - `Linux x64  165.24 MB   jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz`.

After installing the JDK, when I run my java program using `-d64` then everything is as expected because it is in fact a 64 bit installation but when I use `-d32` then I get error saying `Error - This Java instance does not support 32 bit JVM`.

Error is understandable to me, but what confuses me is this line (as in above quoted para) *"The options -d32 and -d64 have been added to the Java launcher to specify whether the **program** is to be run in a 32 or 64-bit environment."*
As per this line, my understanding is that when launching Java of 64 bit version, `-d32` can be used to launch it in 32 bit mode.

**Questions:**

1. Is my understanding correct? And if it is correct, then I am getting error?
2. If my understanding is not true, then why do I need these command-line arguments, because when I will launch Java using `java` then whichever installation (32 bit or 64 bit JDK) is in my PATH will be launched.

Comment: shouldn't the application be compiled for 32 bit in order to be executable for it?

Comment: No .. Then what's the point of Java's "compile once and run anywhere" .. You can compile a java program using 32 compiler and run it in a 64 bit JVM ..

Comment: I could be wrong on that statement, but it could explain. I think the idea of 'run anywhere' has to do with compiling to the JVM instead the hardware. So that the same code can be ran on any kind of computer, Windows/*nix/iOS.

Comment: @Danielson No, that is not how Java works. Java bytecode is platform-independent, you do not compile Java code for 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: Hmm... I see... I'm wrong... But then,,, what ís the explanation, on the question, not my stupidity

Comment: Note that the text you quote is for Solaris, and it has answers for Linux  a few sentences below."All other platforms (Windows and Linux) contain separate 32 and 64-bit installation packages.  If both packages are installed on a system, you select one or the other by adding the appropriate "bin" directory to your path.  For consistency, the Java implementations on Linux accept the -d64 option.  "

Comment: AFAIK that switch only has any effect (other than error) on Solaris. This is according to table 4.4 of Java Performance: The Definitive Guide, I've never tested it myself.

Comment: @nos Then what's the point `-d32` and `-d64` options? And exactly that's what is my second question ..

Comment: @hagrawal Outside of Solaris, nothing.

Comment: @biziclop Makes sense. I think and hope you are right, but unfortunately I don't have Solaris else I would have tested and clarified this .. Lets see if anybody has experience on it ..

Comment: @hagrawal The -d32 and -d64 works as described on Solaris as long as both 32 and 64 bit pacages are installed, but not on other platforms. (Albeit on Linux the 64 bit JVM accepts -d64 also)

Comment: @hagrawal I don't have experience with Solaris, so I can't confirm if `-d32` and `-d64` work there. I do with Linux and Windows though and I know they don't. The way you choose which JVM to run is to run the appropriate `java`/`java.exe` executable.

Comment: All, check this line from same link "For the Solaris 64-bit packages, you must first install the 32-bit SDKor JRE and then select and install the 64-bit package on top of the 32-bit version. " Looks like @biziclop could be right .. In case of Solaris, looks like in same installation of JDK/JRE you can have 32 and 64 bit version .. So, you can use `-d32` and `-d64` to differentiate Java launching ..

Comment: @nos Ok, thanks. So, does this means these options are only useful in case of Solaris, and when both 64 and 32 bit versions are installed? I couldn't understand "Albeit on Linux the 64 bit JVM accepts -d64 also" part .. In Linux, I have tested and both doesn't work .. In Solaris, you can have different installations of 32 and 64 bit or 64 bit can only installed on top of 32 bit, as suggested in the link I shared?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The citation you made:

> The options -d32 and -d64 have been added to the Java launcher to specify whether the program is to be run in a 32 or 64-bit environment.

is valid only for the Solaris operating system.

Later in the [JDK's FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_layering), we can read:

> All other platforms (Windows and Linux) contain separate 32 and 64-bit installation packages.  If both packages are installed on a system, you select one or the other by adding the appropriate "bin" directory to your path.  For consistency, the Java implementations on Linux accept the -d64 option.

So to answer your second question, in Windows and in Linux, theses flags are useless and the 32/64 bit selection is done by running the corresponding JVM installation.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I did read that from JDK FAQ and that's what I asked in my 2nd question. I have to add the "bin" path in the PATH variable then essentially -d32 and -d64 will loose effect because if 32 installation is in the PATH then -d64 will not work. I agree with you on the part that -d32 and -d64 are only for Solaris.

Comment: Thank you. Have you worked on Solaris any time? I was wondering how things happen in Solaris, is that JDK installation path will be set/exported in some env. variable or PATH? If so then what will happen if path of 32bit is set and while launching Java, -d64 is used ??

Comment: I was working on Solaris a long time ago... In the FAQ, it's written `you must first install the 32-bit SDKor JRE and then select and install the 64-bit package on top of the 32-bit version`. It probably means that, there is one entry point and that the selection is then done through `-d32`/`-d64`

Comment: I think that's the only thing which is making sense after all this discussion that in only Solaris you can use -d32 and -d64, and why because probably there both 32 and 64 bit version lies in same installation, as mentioned in JDK FAQ from this line - `Since Solaris has both a 32 and 64-bit J2SE implementation contained within the same installation of Java, you can specify either version.` However, I was looking for someone who has actually some hands on Solaris and did this. Anyways, thanks for your inputs. I will accept your answer.