# Set Heap Size in GB for Tomcat 7.0 in Windows Server 2012

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, tomcat7

I'm stuck at this problem for a long time without finding any solution.

I have the following Java Options in my `Tomcat7_1w.exe`:

(I don't have a setenv.bat or catalina.bat)

```
-Dcatalina.home=G:\Server\Tomcat_1
-Dcatalina.base=G:\Server\Tomcat_1
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=G:\Server\Tomcat_1\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=G:\Server\Tomcat_1\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=G:\Server\Tomcat_1\conf\logging.properties
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=3600
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Dserver
-D64
-Xmx8g
-Xms2g
```

But I get the following error:

> [2018-03-09 16:01:29] [error] [12196] CreateJavaVM Failed
>   [2018-03-09 16:01:29] [error] [12196] The system could not find the environment option that was entered.
>   [2018-03-09 16:01:29] [error] [ 1620] Failed to start Java
>   [2018-03-09 16:01:29] [error] [ 1620] ServiceStart returned 4

I tried `-Xmx4g`, `-Xmx4G` still the same error.

Options that work:

```
-Dcatalina.home=G:\Server\Tomcat_1
-Dcatalina.base=G:\Server\Tomcat_1
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=G:\Server\Tomcat_1\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=G:\Server\Tomcat_1\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=G:\Server\Tomcat_1\conf\logging.properties
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=3600
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Dserver
-Xmx1024m
-Xms512m
```

Also, if I use the option `-d64` (with small **d**), I get the same error. The capital **D** does not give an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31078803/424903), the -d32 or -d64 option only has effect on Solaris platforms so there is no need for you to apply it. That -Dserver is either not complete, or you were looking to configure **-server**.

Comment: @glytching How do I check the version of my JVM? I have a `jre6` folder in `Program files` and `jre1.8.0_121` folder in `Program Files (x86)` folder

Comment: You run **java -version** to see what the default java version of the system is. I do believe tomcat also logs it somewhere, so if you try with a parameter setup that works then you should be able to verify it in one of the log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options -d32 and -d64 do not work on windows. You should select according bin folder with JRE (32 or 64 bit) in system PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks for the info, helped me solve my problem! I figured out not just the  JRE version was 32bit, but also the Tomcat version was 32bit. I had to install 64bit versions of both and then I was able to set the desired heap size.

Answer (score 0):

#### Additional info:

From [Dariusz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49197164/1393400), in Windows, you can't switch between 32 bit and 64 bit using Java options, instead you need to install the desired version of JVM.

In case you are getting the following error:

> %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>   Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\server\jvm.dll

Then there is a version mismatch between your JVM and Apache Tomcat i.e., one is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit. Both need to be the same version.